# Cellkon A90 Android phone not able to get GPS location through GPS Satellite

Tags: android, http, gps, supl

I am building an app for location tracking in android my app is working fine in all the phone i tried so far but when i put my App on cellkon A90 it is giving error.

- Remote side abort the session (receive supl end)

if i turn down GPS and try to access location through network than when i m sending the http then sometime it is giving me

```
connection time out exception, 
unknown host exception,
java.net.SocketException: No route to host
```

i am not getting whats this error is.In my code i am just fetching the cordinates and sending it to my server through HTTP.
This problem is coming in this phone only